# Building a Query that breaks out spend by month. (turning one row into multiple rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So currently each record has a start date, end date and a spend metric.

Lets say one placement (record) started on **1/1/2016** and ends on **3/31/2016** and has a total spend of $1,000.  Ideally I'm looking for the query to to break that record out into 4 records:

- January: $344.44
- February: $311.11
- March: $344.44

In excel I would normally use a formula similar to the one in the link attached: http://www.excel-university.com/excel-formula-to-allocate-an-amount-into-monthly-columns/

My current query is as followed:

```
select placement_id, placement_start_date, placement_end_date, 
ordered_net from agency_views_mbox.digital_placement
```

NOTE: I'm using **Aginity** Workbench for **Redshift** and i've found that a few random SQL functions aren't compatible within Aginity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table or view that represents the months and join  with the spend table based on the start and end dates. That should give you a row for each month that the record spans.

There are many ways that you could do this, in this example, 
I will ask you to create a **tally** table (google it or StackOverflow)  which contains integers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,... in a single column n, you can adjust the number of months and the start date to suit your data.

Note I have used nextMonthStart, as it is easier that subtracting the single day from each month, as I can just use < rather than <= in the later join, I only needed to subtract the single day in one place this way.

```
CREATE VIEW MonthList 
as 
SELECT TOP (240) 
    DATEADD(month, n, '2000-01-01') as MonthStart
  , DATEADD(month, n + 1, '2000-01-01') as NextMonthStart
FROM tally
```

Secondly, calculate the number of days that the record overlaps the month * the average daily spend.

For tidyness I am going to assume your table is just called placement.
Note I have haad to cast your ordered_net and the placement duration before the division, you may need to change the data type to suit your database and data.

```
select 
    placement_id
  , placement_start_date
  , placement_end_date
  ,  DailySpend * DATEDIFF(day, PeriodStart,  PeriodEnd) as PeriodSpend
FROM (
    SELECT placement_id
         , placement_start_date
         , placement_end_date
         , CAST(ordered_net as decimal(12,5))
             / CAST( DATEDIFF(day, placement_start_date, placement_end_date) as decimal(12.5)) as DailySpend
         , CASE WHEN placement_start_date >  monthStart THEN placement_start_date else monthStart end as PeriodStart
       , CASE WHEN placement_end_date <  nextmonthStart THEN placement_end_date else DATEADD(day, -1, nextmonthStart) end as PeriodEnd
   from placement inner join 
     monthList on placement_start_date < nextMonthStart 
     and placement_end_date >= monthStart
 ) as monthlyCalcs
```

This should work in sql-server, you may need to make minor changes to the DATEDIFF calculations, the form of the JOIN and the CAST for alternative databases.

**EDIT** 
You can expose more of the data in the outer query so that you an verify that the number of days for each period is correct. You could also add the text description to the MonthList view so that you can see which month the row applies too. Don't forget to sum the values to check that the "pro rate" has split the values correctly.

Comment: Pat, how did you get on with splitting the results by month?

Comment: Mike - Thanks for the reply... was out on vacation...just getting to this now. Hopefully i will be able to work through all of this.  I'll keep you UTD.  Thanks